# Is it possible to do a USB File Transfer on a Motorola Droid X2?

Tags: android

I just got a Droid X2 and I want to mount my MicroSD located in my Droid X2 on my laptop running **Ubuntu 11.04**, and I am wondering if there are some drivers, or a program I need to install, because I just bough a usb cable for it.

My Droid X2 is currently running android 2.3.4.

Comment: You need more detail in your question. Are you trying to transfer a file between your phone and your computer, phone to USB device, what? If the answer to the above question is computer, what os is it running? Please edit your post to fill in these details. If the question does not have anything to do with Ubuntu, it does not belong on this stack exchange site.

Comment: @William, alright, I updated my question

Comment: Alright, that's a lot better. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do it just by selecting "USB mass storage". :)